# Can there be a variable sent to 2 or more JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to coding so I am working with JSP. My issue is
that I have a login form and that form I send it to a profile page, but I have a "check grades" page too, and I kind of need that variable

Login

```
<form ACTION="Notas.jsp" METHOD="POST">
    <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
    USUARIO <input type="text" name="txtUsu" value="Ingresar Usuario">
    PASSWORD <input type="password" name="txtPas" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="btnClickPapa" value="Entrar">
</form>`
```

So right now I working with my "Notas.jsp" (Grades), but I have my profile page too ("Entraste.jsp"), I have tried to form and send the variable from my login to my "Entraste.jsp" and then there should be a link "Check my grades" and when I click it it should appear my "Notas.jsp", but in the last part, the values captured are null, I know I should be working with servlet, but I can't because I am limited to work with JSP and don't know much about servlet eitherway

So Can I do like Login.jsp -> Profile.jsp -> Grades.jsp send variables from one jsp to the other corner? Or I have to do it in another way? If there is please tell me

Answer (score 0):

As http is stateless, if you want the data across multiple pages, you need to add data (attributes) to `javax.servlet.httpHttpSession` object and can be retrieved across the pages.

You can look HttpSession API at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

**UPDATE1:**

You can use `HttpSession` inside your JSP pages as well becase `session` is an implicit object in JSP.

You can look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) for JSP implicit objects.

Comment: I know it is more viable working with servlets, but like I stated I am limited with JSP,  so there is no way I can send it to 2 or more JSP files? Thanks for the reply man!

Comment: you can use session.setAttribute() and session.getAttribute() in JSP as well